# regression - statistical significance query

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution

1) Why do we do statistical tests to check if the independent variables used in the regression are statistically significant or not, when it can be checked using correlation?
2) My understanding is when we have only one continuos variable - we check if the data given is normally distributed or not and then compute statistics for the historical data - which we better coin this term as descriptive statistics.
Not sure where it is used in real -life, normally my understanding is that continuous variables are better understood based on the context of one dim. Let me know your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

There main reason is that we want to be sure that the "correlation" between the two variables (meaning the coefficient of the regression) did not occur by pure random chance. There are a lot of assumptions that go in to making this valid, but if those assumptions hold, statistical significance is one way to decide how confident we are in the results.